# Is it possible to define an inner product in this vector space to make it an inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

This is for curiousity; whether or not it is possible and if so, how/what would be the inner product?
Vector space is defined by $(\mathbb{R}^{+},\oplus,\otimes,\mathbb{R})$
where $x\oplus y = x \times y$ and
$x \otimes y = y^x$.

Comment: That is not a vector space; whatever vector addition is supposed to be is not commutative.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Since $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, $x\times y=y\times x$...

Comment: You know, once you get an answer to the question, it's sort of polite to either accept it or explain why it is not what you were looking for...

Comment: @5xum Sorry, I haven't had time to attempt it using your hint as I've had work for almost the whole day for the last couple of days. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Oh, sorry then. There's just so many hit-and-run questions lately I'm a little jaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Given that your vector space is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R, +,\times, \mathbb R$) with standard scalar multiplication and addition, and knowing that the isomorphism is $$x\mapsto e^x$$

you can start from here.

You know that in the standard vector space, $\langle x, y\rangle=x\cdot y$ is an inner product. So, the idea is that you take $x,y$ in *your* vector space, map them to the *standard* vector space, and calculate their inner product there.